# Issue with saving text with format "<save text in this description area>" in textbox

Tags: asp.net

I am new to c# asp.net and my job is to understand the existing code and make changes for new requirement's.

I have a web form were one of the field is a textbox

**Purpose**: users writes description of the issue in this area in the following format "<save text in this description area>"

**Issue**: I can't save the form when I write the text format "<save text in this description area>" please let me know if the text can be saved in the issue format I described above if so kindly let me know the solution..

**Note**: Sql database is used as a backend to save the data.

If I am missing any details or info to be shared please let me know..thanks in advance.

I would like to make share here my findings I able to save the data in the following format

1. < save text in this description area> (*here I had a space in between < and save*)
2. " save text in this description area> (*here I did not put any < sign at the start*)

Comment: show the query.. and which `sql` database `sql-server` , `mysql`

Comment: please show some code - what does the textbox look like, what does the backend try to do with the values entered into the textbox? Is there any javascript interacting with the textbox?

Comment: on an unrelated sidenote, please read this before posting http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: FYI Pl: I am able to save and see the data if the text format is "< save text description>" here if you observe there is space between < and save so in these case the data is saved and seen at the debug point textdescription.text and saved in the sql database.The issue is for "<save text description" in these case if you see there is space between < and save

Comment: when i try to submit now i get the following error:Unhandled exception at line 513, column 13 in localhost:49324/… 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: Note: i am using sql server. and the framework is  3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client` error, this will occur because you are passing `<`, `>` with the text entered in the textbox which is dangerous as user can inject scripts in your web application.

You can add following line to prevent this but please note **it is the responsibility of the page developer to ensure that content is properly encoded or processed.**

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If your are targetting ASP.NET 4, you need to add this in Web.Config file as well:-

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Read this [Article](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation) for more.

**Edit:**

You can encode the text input by user like this:-

```
Server.HtmlEncode(YourTextBoxId.Text);
```

Comment: FYI Pl: I am able to save and see the data if the text format is "< save text description>" here if you observe there is space between < and save so in these case the data is saved and seen at the debug point textdescription.text and saved in the sql database.The issue is for "<save text description" in these case if you see there is space between < and save.

Comment: when i try to submit now i get the following error:Unhandled exception at line 513, column 13 in http://localhost:49324/ScriptResource.axd?d=_BVt7geeKdNNKmH7keWQloB-_UhjxiXbsGvwwI4Nf-rlBuVWM9ArL-IAom0FNi09x8WkOspWA06P0X1GTZX5V7x8SdidNMN4ovpT3vA3PCbuD3wOqM71GBfhofIYkBv9dhBdWDlNVzxLNDPKGMwCaeSZW3dOPPY_bC1KRvCmRm4LLy_d0&t=fffffffff98cfb72
  
 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: Hey thanks Rahul.. I figured it out with your advice.. from above shared code lines by you,Now I made in my web.config file <pages validateRequest="false" />  I can save the format I mean ["<save text description>"] ,now as its not a good practise to make validationRequest=false giving malicious users option to send scripts - where I saw in few articles , Do you have any code/solution using javascript (by writing onclientclick() function) ,the end result I wish to have is not to make ValidiationRequest=false and to capture the data entered in textbox and pass it to serverside code. minutes

Comment: @Ashwin - I am not sure about doing that with Javascript. You can refer to this Code project article and see it this helps:- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det

Comment: sure Rahul.. I will accept as an answer for finding out my issue but will really help me if you can advise a better solution or code with me. :) apart from <page validationRequest="false">

Comment: @Ashwin - You can do that on page level rather than turning it on for entire application like this: `<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> ` Also, do HTMl encode as I have mentioned in my edit, it will not run the script, rather it will store that directly.

Comment: <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> is a gud suggest however it works fine on my local machine but unfortunately when I do the same changes to work on prod server it fails to any suggestion on this please.. is it with ant setting with IIS and my prod server details  are as follows windows 2012 ,OS:windows 8,by default is any security stopping this to work(page validaterequest="false">
Thanks in advance..

Comment: hey rahul - any suggestion please on my above comment line